# Proving weak convergence for a specific function.

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence, solution-verification, weak-convergence

So the function is
$$u_n(x)=\begin{cases} a&\mbox{ if } x\in (\frac{i}{n},\frac{i+1/2}{n}], i=0,\dots,n-1,
\\ b&\mbox{ if } x\in(\frac{i+1/2}{n},\frac{i+1}{n}],i=0,\dots,n-1.\end{cases}$$
in $\textit{L}^1((0,1))$ and i want to show $u_n \rightharpoonup (a+b)/2$.

**Is anybody able to give a cleaver, or anyways simple proof I couldn't see?**
I think i have successfully proven it, although it took way to much effort on a specific step of my "proof".

---

For anybody who is interested this is **my attempt**:

Using density of the [simple functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_function) in $\textit{L}^{\infty}((0,1))$, i must prove the definition for weak converges holds, but i can restrict the argument to simple functions.

So given a simple function $\overline{g}$ i know there exist costants $c_1=0<c_2<\cdots<c_k=1$ such that $\overline{g}$ is costant on these, so you can come to this partial conclusion:
$$\lim_{n\to +\infty} \int_{(0,1)}\overline{g}u_ndm=\lim_{n\to +\infty}\sum_{j=1}^{k-1}\overline{g}(c_i)\int_{c_j}^{c_{j+1}}u_n(z)dz=\sum_{j=1}^{k-1}\overline{g}(c_j)\lim_{n\to +\infty}\int_{c_j}^{c_{j+1}}u_n(z)dz=$$
$$= \sum_{j=1}^{k-1}\overline{g}(c_j)\biggl[ \lim_{n\to +\infty}\int_{(0,1)}a\chi_{E_n^{(j)}}(z)dz + \lim_{n\to +\infty}\int _{(0,1)}b\chi_{F_n^{(j)}}(z)dz \biggl] =$$
$$= (\star)\sum_{j=1}^{k-1}\overline{g}(c_j)\biggl[ a \lim_{n\to +\infty}|E_n^{(j)}| + b \lim_{n\to +\infty}|F_n^{(j)}| \biggl](\star)$$
where
$$E_n^{(j)}:=\biggl{\{} \bigcup_{i\le n-1}\biggl(\frac{i}{n},\frac{i+1/2}{n} \biggr] \bigcap (c_j,c_{j+1}) \biggr{\}} \mbox{ e } F_n^{(j)}:=\biggl{\{} \bigcup_{i\le n-1}\biggl(\frac{i+1/2}{n},\frac{i+1}{n} \biggr] \bigcap (c_j,c_{j+1}) \biggr{\}} \mbox.$$

These next step is where i think i put to much effort for a proof like this, but i am simply finding the limit of the measure of these two sets.

Lets take  $I_n^{(j)}:=\{ i\le n-1:\bigl(\frac{i}{n},\frac{i+1}{n}\bigr]\subseteq (c_j,c_{j+1}) \}$, by definition
$$(\star \star)E_n^{(j)} \supseteq \bigcup_{i\in I_n^{(j)}}\biggl(\frac{i}{n},\frac{i+1/2}{n}\biggr] \mbox{ e } F_n^{(j)} \supseteq \bigcup_{i\in I_n^{(j)}}\biggl(\frac{i+1/2}{n},\frac{i+1}{n}\biggr] (\star \star)\mbox,$$

and we can observe that for $n \ge \frac{2}{(c_{j+1}-c_j)}$ we get
$$\bigcup_{l=0}^{\lfloor n(c_{j+1}-c_j)\rfloor-1} \biggl( c_j+\frac{l}{n},c_j+\frac{l+1}{n} \biggr]  \mbox{, with measure } \le |(c_j,c_{j+1})|$$
and $\exists$ $\overline{i}\in I_n^{(j)}$ such that
$$\frac{\overline{i}}{n}\in \biggl[c_j,c_j + \frac{1}{n}\biggr)\mbox,$$
We can observe that we can obtain our sets
$$ \bigcup_{i\in I_n^{(j)}}\biggl(\frac{i}{n},\frac{i+1}{n}\biggr] \mbox,$$
by a translation $\le 1/n$ to the right of the sets $\bigcup_{l=0}^{\lfloor n(c_{j+1}-c_j)\rfloor-1} \biggl( c_j+\frac{l}{n},c_j+\frac{l+1}{n} \biggr]$. With this process i might loose the last of my intervals, but I loose at most one.

So i can deduce this: $|I_n^{(j)}| \ge \lfloor n(c_{j+1} - c_j) \rfloor -1 \ge n(c_{j+1}-c_j)-2$.

Now, using $(\star \star)$,

$$\lim_{n\to +\infty}|E_n^{(j)}| \ge \lim_{n\to +\infty}\sum_{i\in I_n^{(j)}}\biggl| \biggl( \frac{i}{n},\frac{i+1/2}{n}  \biggr] \biggr| = \lim_{n\to +\infty}\sum_{i\in I_n^{(j)}}\frac{1}{2n} = \lim_{n\to +\infty}\frac{|I_n^{(j)}|}{2n} \ge$$
$$\ge \lim_{n\to +\infty}\frac{n(c_{j+1}-c_j)-2}{2n} = \frac{(c_{j+1}-c_j)}{2}$$
and in the same way
$$\lim_{n\to +\infty}|F_n^{(j)}| \ge \frac{(c_{j+1}-c_j)}{2} \mbox,$$
but since we have also that $|E_n^{(j)} \cup F_n^{(n)}|=|E_n^{(j)}|+|F_n^{(j)}|=|(c_j,c_{j+1})|=(c_{j+1}-c_j)$, we can deduce that
$$\lim_{n\to +\infty}|E_n^{(j)}|=\lim_{n\to +\infty}|F_n^{(j)}|=\frac{(c_{j+1}-c_j)}{2} \mbox.$$

This holds $\forall 1\ge j\ge k-1$, so now if we take
$$n\ge \max_{j}\biggl{\{} \frac{2}{(c_{j+1}-c_j)} \biggr{\}}$$
we can conclude our first series of equalities in $(\star)$ with:
$$=\lim_{n\to +\infty}\int_{(0,1)}\overline{g}u_ndm = \sum_{j=1}^{k-1} \overline{g}(c_j)\frac{(a+b)}{2}(c_{j+1}-c_j)=\sum_{j=1}^{k-1}\int_{c_j}^{c_{j+1}}\overline{g}(z)\frac{(a+b)}{2}dz=\int_{(0,1)}\overline{g}(z)\frac{(a+b)}{2}dz \mbox,$$
which is exactly what we wanted.

Comment: Even though it has some benefits in solving this problem by "brute" force as you have shown, why don't you use any theorem?

Comment: No useful theorem came to mind, what known result do you suggest?

Comment: So you read it, did you find logical gaps?

Comment: I didn't read it all, the direction seems okay. If $\mu$ is a positive measure (i.e $a,b \ge 0$ ), you can use the convergence of cumulative distribution function to prove your desired result.

Comment: Or you can prove the weak convergence with any polynomial function first then use Weierstrass theorem to conclude.

Comment: When either $a$ or $b <0$, you can subtract your measure by another measure to have a positive measure.

Comment: I guess I don't know these results, only partially Weiestrasss's theorem, which i don't know would help. In fact I still used density of some functions, in particular simple functions, which at least in an intuitive way seem easier to deal with to me.

Comment: I see you  are considering $u$ a measure, so you may be talking about things i don't know, at least yet. In fact I read about some other type of weak convergence (maybe *weak convergence) that deals with measures; are you talking about this?

Comment: Anyways I didn't take the time to thank you, so thank you for dealing with me!!!

Comment: I see what you mean, I didn't understand clearly your question. Maybe there are other theorems, anyway, it seems to me that  Weierstrass theorem stills work for this.

Comment: I'll try to post an answer to your question

Comment: It's somehow confusing. You're using the same symbol to denote the index of the sum that defines $\bar{g}$ and the index of the limit, for instance.

Comment: I edited it, anyways throughout the paper the number of constants was $k$, as now the first line states. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, a possible solution can be like this.

For simplicity, assume $a,b>0$
Let $\mu$ be the limit measure to which we want to prove the convergence. 
Firstly, we can prove that $$ \int f d\mu_n \rightarrow  \int fd\mu$$
for all continuous function $f$ on $[0,1]$.
The passage from continuous functions to measurable ones is in the following.

Because $\mathcal{C}([0,1])$  is a subset dense of $L^1$, for all $f \in L^1$ and $\epsilon>0$, there is a function $g \in \mathcal{C}([0,1])$ such that:
$$\| f-g\|_1 < \epsilon $$
Therefore, for all $n$,
$$ \left|\int f d\mu_n - \int f d\mu\right| \le  \left|\int g d\mu_n- \int g d\mu\right|  +\underbrace{\left| \int (f-g)d\mu_n \right|}_{\le (a+b)\epsilon} + \underbrace{\left| \int (f-g)d\mu \right|}_{\le (a+b)\epsilon} $$
Thus,
$$ \limsup \left|\int f d\mu_n - \int fd\mu\right| \le 2(a+b)\epsilon$$
Hence,
$ \lim  \int f d\mu_n = \int f d\mu$
for all $f \in L^1$
As $L^{\infty}[0,1] \subset L^{1}[0,1]$, we have the conclusion.
$\square$

Comment: I could not understand the whole proof becouse I still have to see how one defines weak convergence of measures (weak convergence I was talking about is defined on $L^p$ functions, once given the weak topology, and so on...). Other than this, I don't get how this shows it converges to $(a+b) /2$ and not, for example, to $(a+b) $, but I think it might just be becouse I am going to have to go define weak convergence on measures.

Comment: I see. As a probabilist, I'm more used to weak convergence of measures than the weak convergence in $L^p$ sense.